# How to use exception handling in zend framework php?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

```
try {
    if ($user_session_object['device_type'] == '1') {
        $this->sendNotificationAndroidOne($notificationData);
    }
    throw new Exception("newInner");
    //throw new Exception("newInner");
    if ($user_session_object['device_type'] == '2') {
        $this->sendNotificationIphone($notificationData);
    }
}catch(Exception $ex){
    echo 'Exception occur while send push notification';
    exit;
}
```

Getting error: Exception' not found in file. Thanks in advance

Comment: `throw new Exception("newInner");` doesnt make sense within the try block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely a namespace issue (nothing to do with Zend Framework), so you want `throw new \Exception("newInner");` and `catch(\Exception $ex)`.

Otherwise, please add the full error message to your question.

Answer (score 2):

As per your code "`throw new Exception("newInner")`" it have not makes any sence inside `try{}` block, because whenever an exception will be found `catch(){}` block will be called.

You should use `try---catch` like below.

```
     try{
        if ($user_session_object['device_type'] == '1') {
            $this->sendNotificationAndroidOne($notificationData);
        }           
        if ($user_session_object['device_type'] == '2') {
            $this->sendNotificationIphone($notificationData);
        }
    }catch (\Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
        var_dump($e->getCode());
        exit;
    }
```